# Java convert date from one format to another

Tags: java, type-conversion

How can I convert date form  to

> 2013-01-10 09:49:19

to

> 10th Jan.

both values are of string types.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I can't imagine how you were able to *not* find how to parse and format dates in Java with Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the code to work out the correct suffix as this isn't part of the standard JDK.  To be fair that's probably the only bit of this question that isn't just a `SimpleDateFormat#format()` call.

```
static String[] suffixes =
          //    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
             { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
          //    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
               "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
          //    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29
               "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
          //    30    31
               "th", "st" };

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    String string = "2013-01-10 09:49:19";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    String dayStr =
            dayFormat.format(date)
                    + suffixes[Integer.parseInt(dayFormat.format(date))]
                    + " " + monthFormat.format(date) + ".";
    System.out.println(dayStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2013-01-10 09:49:19");
String format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'th' MMM").format(date);
System.out.println(format);
```

Output is:

```
10th Jan
```

Comment: This isn't quite right as if it was the 3rd of the month, it'd say 3th Jan, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateFormat class

`DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.ENGLISH);`

`System.out.println(df.parse(myDateInString));`

I think you should surround the statements in try catch for possible exceptions.